# How can I move files by using the keyboard only?

Tags: macos

I'm looking for some kind of a utility that lets me select a file(s) and then say hit a command key and then move to a difference directory and hit the command key again and have those files moved to the new location.

I think I have seen some similar apps where you could drop files onto a dock icon to gather them but I cant recall the names.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Move files using just keyboard in Mac Finder?](https://superuser.com/q/46720/100686) for a discussion of the same topic, listing a lot of options.

Assuming you are running Lion you can *move* files by using <kbd>Cmd-C</kbd> to pick them up and <kbd>Cmd-Opt-V</kbd> to move them to the target location.